# SLI Bridge - What is the proper slot spacing

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, sli

I am getting ready to order and install a second EVGA GeForce GTX 960 for a two way SLI. My concern lies with an SLI Bridge. I have a Gigabyte Z170MX-Gaming 5 Motherboard and plan to have the Cards in the first and third slots. *reference image below*

My current card is in slot 1 and spans over slot 1 and slot 2. I know the second card I will be getting will be placed in slot 3 and cover slot 3 and 4.

Here is an image for reference[image: My motherboard with the slots outlined]

I ended up doing some research and found this page here: [Official NVIDIA SLI Bridges](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3576)

However, I can't really understand it :(

So my answer really boils down to, what is the slot spacing number I will need for this setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the cards are two-slot widths, they expect that you'd use slots 1 and 3, and the included SLI bridge should accommodate that.  If you want to use a wider spacing, you can get [longer SLI bridges from nVidia](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/bridges):

[image: nVidia SLI bridges]